# Understanding GPU processes from `nvidia-smi` command

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

I have a new laptop with NVidia RTX 2070 GPU that I'm using to train `tensorflow 2.1` models. Unfortunately I'm having GPU OOM (out of memory) issues - in the middle of training it crashes, I reduced RAM usage *a lot*, but of course the problem still persists.

I tried to check what is causing the GPU go OOM. When I type `nvidia-smi` in the terminal I get the following outputs:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64.00    Driver Version: 440.64.00    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P8     6W /  N/A |   1009MiB /  7982MiB |     11%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1209      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            72MiB |
|    0      1237      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          52MiB |
|    0      1565      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           481MiB |
|    0      1693      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         195MiB |
|    0     12312      G   ...uest-channel-token=14048285025818334832   204MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What are these processes about? Can you help me interpret and understand them? Is there anything I can kill, and how?

Comment: I have the same GPU, but on my nvidia-smi I only have two Xorg processes that are 14 MiB each.  That's all.  Your process that 12312, is that perchange a jupyter notebook?  I find that sometimes these notebooks don't really die when I kill them, and periodically have do a `ps aux | grep jupyter` to find them and kill them.

Comment: I'm not using Jupyter, I'm calling a `train.py` script from terminal. Do you think there is something wrong with my process queue?

Comment: I'm not sure.  You could try rebooting or killing those processes (which will log you out), and after that, maybe decrease the batch size for your training?  If your code supports mixed precision (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/mixed_precision) you could try enabling that too.

Comment: Can you write an answer on how to do that? I'm sorry I'm a GPU rookie. Also, what is the command to kill jupyter processes, just in case?

Answer (score 0):

All of the processes are  X-windows display processes. If your laptop has some sleazy onboard video (many do, for power-saving) you can configure it to use that to drive the display, and that will free up the fancy card for computing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am a newbie about GPUs and I didn't fully understand your comment. What are "onboard video" ? And how can I configure? Also, do you think there is something wrong with my process queue?

Comment: @Leevo THere is nothing wrong with your process queue. As for how you can configure, this is a linux question https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/738shq/optimus_how_to_force_xorg_to_use_intel_gpu/

Comment: Is it possible to force my computer to run `Xorg` and `gnome-shell` to use CPU instead of GPU?

Comment: @leevo Since we are talking about the video driver, you have to use the GPU sometime.